# Port forward requests from 80 to respective ports

Tags: spring-boot, portforwarding, digital-ocean, embedded-tomcat-7

I have many spring boot jars running in different ports. Say 9087-9090. I have a domain say 
mydomain.com.

I can access mydomain.com:9087/ and use the application. Also mydomain.com:9088/ and use another application but how can i use them just like mydomain.com and still map them to desired ports. What is the technical term for this.

I use digitalocean hosting and have a  Ubuntu 14.04 x64 Box. I'm running Java 7 in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reverse proxy (a.k.az front end load balancer) with URL rewriting. I'm not sure what you hosting solution offers or permits, but you could try nginx or Apache httpd if you want something running locally. There are also service providers you might be able to use outside your host.